# How to use a "for" loop inside children of a widget?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am really confused with this, where should the FOR LOOP be placed, so that I don't get an error in flutter? As you can see on the picture, it has red underlines and it says.

[image]

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Two alternatives :

```
final children = <Widget>[];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  children.add(new ListTile());
}
return new ListView(
  children: children,
);
```

or

```
return new ListView(
  children: new List.generate(10, (index) => new ListTile()),
);
```

Comment: this does not work if I place it in to the CHILDREN of EXPANDED(),
note: I am new to flutter

Comment: .. which is a definition of a list (your `[]`). You can't put a for loop directly inside a list definition, so Rémi shows how you can create the list first, then give it to the property.

Answer (score 38):

There are multiple ways of using a `for` loop in children for widgets like `ListView`, `Column`, etc.

- Using a `for` loop

  ```dart
  ListView(
    children: [
      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) Text('Item $i'),
    ],
  )
  ```
- Using a `for-each` loop

  ```dart
  ListView(
    children: [
      for (var item in items) Text(item),
    ],
  )
  ```
- Combining `...[]` with `for` loop

  ```dart
  ListView(
    children: [
      ...[
        Text('Item 0'),
        Text('Item 1'),
      ],
      for (var item in items) Text(item), // Rest of the items
    ],
  )
  ```

Comment: How can I add multiple widgets in the loop? I cannot use `{ }` or `[ ]`.

Comment: @AlexVang Use `...[child1, child2]`

Comment: What if I want to put a print("xx"); inside the for loop to see how the children are being rendered? it doesnt allow me !?

Comment: best answer . good keep .God bless you.

Comment: All these response examples run correctly only if you use 1 simple widget declaration. If you need more complex instruction this response not response of your requirement

Answer (score 14):

We can use the spread operator also to add multiple widgets using for the loop

```dart
Column(
 children: [
 Container() /// we can add some other widgets
 for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) ...[
    CardListItem(),
    Divider(),
  ],
]
```

Comment: This is the best !!! Thanks for the answer !! I was trying to use a ListView.builder inside a Row with a Container with dynamic size, it was impossible and this solve my problem.

Comment: how to do 2d matrix kind of loops ? for inside for?

Comment: you can write for inside for loops without any issue

Answer (score 5):

Simple for loop in flutter using json response

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var list = [{'id':"123123","date":"20/08/2016"},{'id':"123124","date":"26/08/2016"},{'id':"123125","date":"26/08/2016"}]; 
   return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Recent Claims'),
        Table(
          border: TableBorder.all(color: Colors.black),
          columnWidths: {
            0: FixedColumnWidth(100.0),
            1: FixedColumnWidth(100.0)
          },
          children:[
            for(var item in list )  TableRow(children: [
              Text(item['id']),
              Text(item['date']),
          ])]
           ),
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a `List`:

```dart
ListView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  children: List.generate(10, (index) => …),
),
```

Else:

```dart
ListView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  children: list.map((e) => …).toList(),
),
```