# The method '>' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: >(1e-10) The relevant error-causing widget was Column

Tags: flutter, dart

I was writing this piece of code:

```
Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            GridView.count(
              crossAxisSpacing: 10,
              mainAxisSpacing: 1,
              crossAxisCount: 7,
              children: <Widget>[
                for (int c = 0; c < 10 /*0000*/; c++)
                  InkWell(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: dateColors[c],
                      ),
                      child: setDay(c),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        changeColors(c);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
              ],
            ),
            ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("I'm dedicating every day to you"),
                Text('Domestic life was never quite my style'),
                Text('When you smile, you knock me out, I fall apart'),
                Text('And I thought I was so smart'),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

I wanted to make a scrollable grid with a scrollable list under that, but I want to make sure that if I scroll the grid the list isn't scrolled and vice versa. The code above doesn't work. Does anyone know why? I'm still a newbie in Flutter and I'm trying to learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use method to create list of `inkWell`s and call it as children of the GridView.

```
Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        GridView.count(
          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
          mainAxisSpacing: 1,
          crossAxisCount: 7,
          children: _createInkWellWidgets(),
        ),
        ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("I'm dedicating every day to you"),
            Text('Domestic life was never quite my style'),
            Text('When you smile, you knock me out, I fall apart'),
            Text('And I thought I was so smart'),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    )

List<Widget> _createInkWellWidgets() {
  List<Widget> widgets = [];
  for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
    widgets.add(InkWell(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: dateColors[c],
        ),
        child: setDay(c),
      ),
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          changeColors(c);
        });
      },
    ));
  }
  return widgets;
}
```

Comment: can you identify the line in which the error happen? give me the whole error massage.

Comment: I have Visual Studio Code. I don't know how to copy the whole error message.

Comment: I have edited the answer. the loop condition was wrong. If it not working then the problem may be in either your `changeColors` , `setDay` or `dateColors`

Comment: A bit of time has passed but the problem has actually been solved. It's exactly as in your answer but `shrinkWrap: true` has to be included not only in `ListView` but also in `GridView.count`.

Answer (score 0):

You missed `square brackets` after for statement.

If you need to recap how to use `for` in a widget tree take a look here [How to use a "for" loop inside children of a widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670325/how-to-use-a-for-loop-inside-children-of-a-widget)

Comment: It gives me problems if I put brackets after the for statement.

Comment: Create List and add to it items inside for loop. Like in answer from link I added. Then pass this list to widget tree